# PostgreSQL: How to convert comma separated string to work with IN operator

Tags: postgresql

I was trying to make this query to work

```
select *
from DUALS
where num in ('1,2,3')
```

string '1,2,3' creating on the fly, so i cant replace it as list of integers in code.

So I end with this:

```
select *
from DUALS
where num in (select unnest (string_to_array('1,2', ',')::integer[]))
```

It works, but I'm wondering if it might be simplified. Can't use 'Any' operator.

Comment: I think is simple enough. But if you want can create a function to receive string a return integer[]

Comment: Why can't you use the `ANY` operator?

Comment: Because of cross-platfrom reason. Some DB engines can use ANY predicates only with subqueries, but works fine with in '1,2,3'.

Comment: If this is supposed to be portable, how can you use `unnest` and `string_to_array` or array types in general?

Comment: preprocessor for postgresql in this case. Ugly but works. The way of less resistance for now. In general, original query is portable, but not in postgresql. In postgresql it will look like second query.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this code:

```
select *
from DUALS
where num = any('{1,2,3}'::int[])
```

Comment: >> Can't use 'Any' operator.